# Imageslide with jQuery (Maybe with PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, html

Okay, so I have my div tag here and its css style 'background' is set to default.

For example

```
<div id="slideimage" style="background:url(01.jpg);width:xxpx;height:xxpx;"></div>
```

And I have my next button

```
<a href="#" onClick="nextPhoto()">Next</a>
```

So I want to happen when I clicked on the Next button, the background style of #slideimage will change into 02.jpg. I tried searching with google but it seems it's not functioning properly.

That's all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using some kind of library? or do you just want to change the image?

Comment: Searching with google seems to work for me. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery to do this or php?

Comment: @RobApodaca - Well, I've search how to change css style with jquery and none of them work even though I've change some ids and stuffs.

Comment: @Shadow_boi - lol, i deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this javascript:

```
function nextImage() {
  $('#slideimage').css("background", "url(02.jpg)");
}
```

Here is a slightly more robust demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gQQBL/

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uvohal/2/edit)*

```
var images = [
  '01.jpg',
  '02.jpg',
  '03.jpg'
];

var iN = images.length;
var i = 0;

function changeImage(){
  $('#slideimage').css({background: 'url('+images[++i % iN]+')'});
}

$('#next').click( changeImage );
```

Create an array of images, a var 'index counter' (`i`) and get the number of images in array (`iN`)

than you can easily toggle your images doing this math using Modulo: `++i % iN`